# How to find a best permutation of least consecutive ranges?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Consider a permutation of the integers in $[0, 2^n)$, such as the sequence $[0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7]$ for $n = 3$.

We will consider $2n$ selections of elements in the permutation: For each bit $i$, $0 ≤ i < n$, we select two subsets. One subset is those elements that have bit $i$ in their binary representation set to zero, and another subset is those elements that have bit $i$ set to one.

For example, for $n = 3$:

- For *i* = 0, we get {0, 2, 4, 6} as the “bit 0 is zero” set, and we get  {1, 3, 5, 7} as the “bit 0 is one” set.
- For *i* = 1, we get {0, 1, 4, 5} and {2, 3, 6, 7} respectively.
- For *i* = 2, we get {0, 1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6, 7} respectively.

For each selection, we locate its elements in the permutation and note the number of groups of adjacent positions they form. For example, for bit 0 zero, the elements 0, 2, 4, and 6 appear in two groups in $[0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7]$: 0 by itself and 2, 4, and 6 together (in the order 2 6 4).

Add the number of groups of each of the $2n$ solutions to get a total number of groups. How can we find a permutation that minimizes this total?

eg.
For a permutation of (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), which has 8! permutations
I want to pick below groups of numbers:

- 0,1,2,3: 1 range (**sequential read**)
- 4,5,6,7: 1 range
- 0,1,4,5: 2 ranges (**less sequential read**)
- 2,3,6,7: 2 ranges
- 0,2,4,6: 4 ranges (**completely random read**)
- 1,3,5,7: 4 ranges

total ranges count: 1+1+2+2+4+4 = 14

but in permutation (0,1,3,2,6,4,5,7), total ranges count is: 1+1+2+2+2+2 = 10

- 0,1,2,3: 1 range (**0,1,3,2**,6,4,5,7)
- 4,5,6,7: 1 range (0,1,3,2,**6,4,5,7**)
- 0,1,4,5: 2 ranges (**0,1**,3,2,6,**4,5**,7)
- 2,3,6,7: 2 ranges (0,1,**3,2,6**,4,5,**7**)
- 0,2,4,6: 2 ranges (**0**,1,3,**2,6,4**,5,7)
- 1,3,5,7: 2 ranges (0,**1,3**,2,6,4,**5,7**)

if n is less, we can **brute-force** (iterate over all permutations of `len`!), but if n is bigger?

The next situation is n=16, for a permutation of `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)`, we need to compute sum of range count of the groups:

- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
- 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
- 0,1,2,3, 8,9,10,11
- 4,5,6,7, 12,13,14,15
- ...
- 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
- 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15

How to generate a best permutation of this rule? Or less, how to **prove a minimal range count** of a given n?

The core is to convert it into sequential reading as much as possible to reduce the number of reads!

Comment: What do you mean by range?

Comment: eg, for `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`, I want to pick `0,1,4,5`, then `(0,1)` is a consecutive range, and `(4,5)` also. For this pick, **range count is 2**, now I want to get the **least sum of range count**

Comment: Your question remains unclear. Please go over it carefully, and detail what you mean, and provide more examples.

Comment: Sorry but I think its clear, for `0,1,2,3`, this is a consecutive range in permutation `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, so I only choose once (**sequential read**), but `0,2,4,6` need four times (**random read**)

Comment: I think I understand the question, which can alternatively be phrased as: what permutation of the numbers results in the fewest bit changes while traversing across the rows of a matrix whose columns are the numbers' bit representations. However, from "*eg. For a permutation of ...*" is confusing for me. Especially with the introduction of "range" and "sequential read"

Comment: Appreciate. Because it's from a CS IO scheduling problem, so if different data chunks are adjacent, we can use ONE sequential read, instead of MANY random reads

Comment: Based on @TonyMathew 's rephrase, then the [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) order would be an optimal candidate. Total bit changes along the sequence would be the minimum $2^n-1$, and the total range count would then be $2^n + n - 1$.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you so so much!!! I think that's the final solution!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4785323/89922#comment10174167_4785323), [@TonyMathew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1102817/tony-mathew) rephrased the question as:

> what permutation of the numbers results in the fewest bit changes while traversing across the rows of a matrix whose columns are the numbers' bit representations.

For example, for the sequence $ (0,1,3,2,6,4,5,7)$ from the question,

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
\text{Pos.} & \overset{\text{Bit}}2 & \overset{\text{Bit}}1 & \overset{\text{Bit}}0 & =\text{dec.} \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\\hline
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\\hline
4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\\hline
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\\hline
6 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\\hline
7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\\hline
\\
\text{Bit flips:} & 1 & 3 & 3\\
\text{Ranges:} & 2 & 4 & 4
\end{array}$$

In the "Bit $i$" column, a $0$ means the element in that position would be in the "bit $i$ is zero" set, and a $1$ means that element would be in the complement "bit $i$ is one" set.

When traversing down the "Bit $i$" column, each bit flip ends a range of "sequential read" for a set, so it's better to have fewer total bit flips from all bit columns.

Between every two adjacent positions, since the elements are different, there is at least $1$ total bit flip from all $n$ bits. From a sequence of length $2^n$, there are at least $2^n-1$ total bit flips. So this example sequence is optimal for $n=3$.

The minimum range count is $2^n + n -1$.

---

For other $n$, there's a family of ordering called [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), with the property that "two successive values differ in only one bit", thus optimal for this question.

For $n=4$, using the standard binary-reflected Gray code,

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
\text{Pos.} & \overset{\text{Bit}}3 & \overset{\text{Bit}}2 & \overset{\text{Bit}}1 & \overset{\text{Bit}}0 & =\text{dec.} \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\\hline
3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\\hline
4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\\hline
5 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\\hline
6 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\\hline
7 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\\hline
8 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\\hline
9 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\\hline
10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\\hline
11 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\\hline
12 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\\hline
13 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\\hline
14 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\\hline
15 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\\hline
\\
\text{Bit flips:} & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
\text{Ranges:} & 2 & 3 & 5 & 9
\end{array}$$

A room for improvement is that the range counts are not balanced for the $2n$ sets. The "bit $3$ is zero" set is in $1$ range, while the "bit $0$ is zero" set is split into $5$ ranges. [Balanced Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Balanced_Gray_code) would be another sequence(s) that minimises such difference, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Wonderful anwser. But if Gray code is non-Boolean, eg. a "bit" can be (0,1,2,3), to find minimal digit flips, I guess Gray code still works?

Comment: @ApicTimer There are [non-boolean Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) that may be constructed similarly by reflection.

Comment: @ApicTimer For your example, a base-4 digit is like 2 binary digits combined anyway, so you can look at the $n=4$ example above and convert the binary numbers to base-4 numbers directly.

Comment: Truly grateful~~ :)