# How to find a best permutation of least consecutive range?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Consider a permutation of the integers in $[0, 2^n)$, such as the sequence $[0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7]$ for $n = 3$.

We will consider $2n$ selections of elements in the permutation: For each bit $i$, $0 ≤ i < n$, we select two subsets. One subset is those elements that have bit $i$ in their binary representation set to zero, and another subset is those elements that have bit $i$ set to one.

For example, for $n = 3$:

- For *i* = 0, we get {0, 2, 4, 6} as the “bit 0 is zero” set, and we get  {1, 3, 5, 7} as the “bit 0 is one” set.
- For *i* = 1, we get {0, 1, 4, 5} and {2, 3, 6, 7} respectively.
- For *i* = 2, we get {0, 1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6, 7} respectively.

For each selection, we locate its elements in the permutation and note the number of groups of adjacent positions they form. For example, for bit 0 zero, the elements 0, 2, 4, and 6 appear in two groups in $[0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7]$: 0 by itself and 2, 4, and 6 together (in the order 2 6 4).

Add the number of groups of each of the $2n$ solutions to get a total number of groups. How can we find a permutation that minimizes this total?

Comment: More information: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785323/how-to-find-a-best-permutation-of-least-consecutive-ranges

Comment: I want to know how to get an optimal one, or how to prove a minimal total? Thank you so much~~~

Comment: Please edit the new content into [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4785323/89922) and simplify it if necessary, and [avoid reposting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3795/89922). I found this question interesting since yesterday, that the previous question has more example. Even though I don't have an answer.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will merge this to my previous question